# Open a file and filter it using a regular expression

Tags: regex, file-io, powershell

I have a large logfile and I want to extract (write to a new file) certain rows. The problem is I need a certain row and the row before. So the regex should be applied on more than one row. Notepad++ is not able to do that and I don't want to write a script for that.

I assume I can do that with Powershell and a one-liner, but I don't know where to start ...

The regular expression is not the problem, will be something like that `^#\d+.*?\n.*?Failed.*?$`

So, how can I open a file using the Powershell, passing the regex and get the rows back that fits my expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at `Select-String` and `-context` parameter:

If you only need to display the matching line and the line before, use
(for a test I use my log file and my regex - the date there)

```
Get-Content c:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR\httperr2.log  |
    Select-String '2011-05-13 06:16:10' -context 1,0
```

If you need to manipulate it further, store the result in a variable and use the properties:

```
$line = Get-Content c:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR\httperr2.log  |
        Select-String '2011-05-13 06:16:10' -context 1

# for all the members try this:
$line | Get-Member

#line that matches the regex:
$line.Line
$line.Context.PreContext
```

If there are more lines that match the regex, access them with brackets:

```
$line = Get-Content c:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR\httperr2.log  |
        Select-String '2011-05-13 06:16:10' -context 1
$line[0] # first match
$line[1] # second match
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try it a the moment on my data, not exactly what I had in my mind, but seems to do what I wanted.

Comment: You can use -Context 1,0 if you only want the line before and not the line after.

Comment: Thanks @stej, thanks @OldFart, together with your suggestion it is producing exactly what I wanted.